# Git: is there a way to auto push a subtree?

Tags: git, githooks, git-subtree

I have a big private repository which is maintained on a local network. I'd  like to automatically push a subtree of that repository outside of that network. I need it to be simple:

***Task*** someone pushes to local remote repository --> a subtree is automatically pushed to some other repository

I am not sure if this could be achieved with a server side hook because AFAIK there is no such thing as pushing *subtrees* from bare remotes. I came up with two ideas:

- I could clone the remote on the server and automatically split the subtree in the cloned remote. This doesn't really help because I don't know how to auto-pull the subtree (others also have [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182059/git-subtree-post-hook)).
- Another idea is to write a custom client-side `post-commit-hook` and make every user install it, but this is terrible, isn't it? Git book specifically states that [policies should be enforced on server side](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

Is there a simple way of achieving something like this? Or is this impossible and it's just git abuse?

Comment: You can push from a post-receive hook on a bare remote repository to another remote repo, so what's the problem?

Comment: @wrzasa hey, thanks for asking. Maybe I didn't make this part clear enough: can you push *subtrees* from bare remotes? I thought, since there is no such thing as a working tree on a bare remote, you can't really specify a subtree. E: I edited the question to make it clear

Comment: Didn't use subtrees, but you can always in your hook checkout your repo to a temp dir and then do whatever you need.

Comment: @wrzasa Thanks, I didn't know that. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Good luck! Here you have some hook examples: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Umm, I'm a bit embarrassed. Apparently this was much easier than I thought. Here is a hasty solution which builds on [@wrzasa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1278368/wrzasa) suggestion:

1. Clone your repository on the server to which you are pushing, like this (dir.git is a bare repo):

   ```
   .
   |- dir.git
   |- dir
   ```
2. In `dir` do: `git remote add <remote-name> <remote-address>`
3. In `dir.git/hooks/post-receive` put:

   ```
   #! /bin/bash
   unset GIT_DIR
   cd ../dir
   git pull ../dir.git
   git subtree split --prefix=<subdir-in-dir> --branch=<branch-name>
   git push <remote-name> <branch-name>
   ```

   Remember to make `post-receive` executable. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10513684/4190925) if you wanna know why `unset GIT_DIR` is needed.

That's pretty much it. Now whenever someone pushes to `dir` remote (i.e. `dir.git`) subtree under `<subdir-in-dir>` will be pushed to `<remote-name>`.

Comment: from `git subtree --help`: _--branch=<branch> [...] <branch> must not already exist_ So I suppose You have to delete <branch-name> at the end of the hook procedure; am I right?

Comment: @ardabro I don't see the line you are referring to in the documentation. Which version of git are you using? Also tbh I ended up with a different version of the hook in which it basically pulls from the bare repo and then does `git subtree push --prefix=<dir> <remote-name> <branch-name>`.