# How can I automatically push to subtree when I push to master?

Tags: git, github

How can I automatically push to subtree  when I push to master? My current workflow is to execute this command after push to master:

```
git subtree push --prefix dist origin branch
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate [git-is-there-a-way-to-auto-push-a-subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714487/git-is-there-a-way-to-auto-push-a-subtree)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git: is there a way to auto push a subtree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714487/git-is-there-a-way-to-auto-push-a-subtree)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to make that happen with a Git Hook. Probably `post-receive`

Git Hooks:
https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-receive

It looks like the script here is pretty close to what you need.
[Git: is there a way to auto push a subtree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714487/git-is-there-a-way-to-auto-push-a-subtree)